# Is there a way to resize video?

Tags: php, html

I retrieve embed code videos from my database. However, in db they are 650 x 650. What I want is making them small.

with template lite tag, I tried this

```
<tr>
    <td>Videos</td>
    <td>
        <div height="100" width =" 200" /> 
            {foreach value=movieF from=$movieFragman}
                {$movieF.embedCode} 
            {/foreach}
        </div>
    </td>                
</tr>
```

but `div` does not work. What can I do for that?

With below code , i set the width height of div

```
   </style><style type="text/css">
    {literal}
    div.embed
    {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    }

    {/literal}
    </style>
```

this happens..
[image]

Comment: It's two way, javascript or CSS, please provide code generated by {$movieF.embedCode}

Comment: <embed src="http://www.abc.com/images/player2.swf?video=173350&amp;movieid=1500" wmode="window" bgcolor="#000000" allowfullscreen="true" scale="noScale" width="640" height="483" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">

Comment: The embed code you're using has a "width" and "height" specified in it. Change them. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's work

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.test embed').attr('height','');
       $('.test embed').height(600);
       $('.test embed').attr('width','');
       $('.test embed').width(600);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="test"> 
        <embed src="http://www.abc.com/images/player2.swf?video=173350&amp;movieid=1500%22" wmode="window" bgcolor="#000000" allowfullscreen="true" scale="noScale" width="640" height="483" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes Css doesn't work for embed only for static element like img. Jquery work good see my fast example http://ios.applecult.pl/test.php

Comment: Rafal set your video size 600x600. This does not work. You set your video as 100x100